# Can mysql plugin use multithreading?

Tags: mysql, multithreading

I have a table and I want to add an AFTER trigger to pass some values to a remote web service. Calling a web service can be very time consuming which depends on the network environment. I wonder is it possible to write a MySQL plugin that for each call it creates a thread to call the remote web service and allow the main thread to return immediately, ie, non-blocking web service call by multithreading.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you want to alter MySQL via plugin so that MySQL itself invokes the service in another thread or did I get it wrong?

Comment: I want to create a UDF to invoke the web service in another thread. The after trigger calls that UDF.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a bad choice. It would make more sense to create a message queue service and use UDF to stack the task on the message queue - which can be a local service, written in basically any language. That way you don't have to create threads that handle async web service communication, you only have to send the data to local service, which in turn can perform REST call to the 3rd party and perform MySQL update once the response comes back. How's that sound?

Comment: Good idea. However, I think there is a problem of using message queue here. Data in message queue will be lost when power outage occurs. Another potential problem is if the message volume is big, I am worried that if the memory usage by the message is too large, it will impact the MySQL server.